# Python - Looping over selected indexes in a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of 10 numbers: `a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I want to get the 2nd digit, the 5-8th digits, and the last digit.  Something like:

```
for i in (a[1], a[4:7], a[9]):
    print(i)
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Simple addition: `for i in a[1] + a[4:7] + a[9]:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
import operator
stuff = operator.itemgetter(1,4,5,6,-1)
for thing in stuff(a):
  print(thing)
```

Comment: Consider combining this with a function that parses human-readable ranges as strings. `"1, 4-6, -1" -> operator.itemgetter(1, 4, 5, 6, -1)`.

Comment: @AdamSmith - Are you saying use a function's return value as itemgetter's argument?  I'll have to think about that, distinguishing between the `-6` and the `-1` in that string might be tricky.

Comment: @AdamSmith - the first thing that came to my mind was to use regular expressions, [like this](https://repl.it/repls/NewHandmadeBison), but it is pretty much the same as yours

Answer (score 9):

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.chain(a[1:2], a[4:7], a[9:10]):
    print(i)
```

You need to use single-element slices because [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) requires each arg to be an iterable.

For a dynamic list of iterables, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
iterables = [a[1:2], a[4:7], a[9:10]]
for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterables):  # Better than chain(*iterables)
    print(i)
```

Comment: ooh you're totally right about the single-element slices. I deleted my (rather duplicate) answer, but you may want to include my bit about `itertools.chain.from_iterable` if they have a list of slices already.

Comment: Is there a way to turn the `itertools.chain` into a range?  `range(len(itertools.chain(a[1:2], a[4:7], a[9:10])))` doesn't work.

Comment: @Valachio `chain` returns an iterable, which doesn't support `len`. To use it in the way you describe, make it a list first: `a = list(itertools.chain(a[1:2], a[4:7], a[9:10])); range(len(a))`. However, if that's your use-case, you're better off using list concatenation (see Scott Hunter's answer).

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Perfect, thanks.  I wish I can give more than 1 checkmark for all the great answers.

Comment: @AdamSmith Done!

Comment: @Valachio TBH, I think wwii's answer is the best solution for this particular question since you only want the indicies from a particular list: `opterator.itemgetter(1, 4, 5, 6, 9)(a) == (a[1], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[9])`.

Answer (score 6):

use the unpacking operator `*`

```
for i in (a[1], *a[4:7], a[9]):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could build a new list of the elements you want:

```
for i in (a[1:2]+a[4:7]+a[9:10]):
    print(i)
```

Comment: `for i in [a[1]]+a[4:7]+[a[9]]:`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
for i in [1] + range(4,8) + [9]:
    print a[i]
```